# hide winform when application loses focus

Tags: vb.net

I have a winform that I use to navigate through my excel workbook. The form opens on the Workbook Open event. All works fine, but I just noticed that if my application is open and I open any other, say IE, my winform remains on top and does not hide. Is there a way to tell my form to hide when my workbook or the application lose focus?

I have searched MSDN and the web and could not really find anything?

```
    Private Sub NavigationForm_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    'This procedure runs when the form loads. The procedure displays
    'the form on the upper left hand corner of the main screen.
    'It also disables and hids the btnHideForm button.

    Me.Location = New Point(0, 0)

    With btnHideForm

        .Visible = True
        .Enabled = True

    End With


End Sub

Public Class ThisWorkbook

Private Sub ThisWorkbook_Startup() Handles Me.Startup

    Dim navForm As New frmNavigation
    navForm.Show()


End Sub
```

This is the code running on form load and on the workbook open

Comment: Are you setting the windows TopMost Property when you are creating your window? It would help if you showed us the code that instantiates the form.

Comment: Thank you. My topMost is set to True. I updated my previous comment with my code

Comment: In order to  get the form behind other windows, you will need to set the TopMost Property to false, also is the a vba application?